# divs in html newsletters

Tags: html, html-email

Can we use divs in html email news letters or is it customary to do everything with tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Div's work fine in HTML emails, but you'll have to embed the CSS in the email or reference it from a public HTTP location to get the formatting you desire.

Comment: Actually, you are best to avoid divs, as they are treated inconsistently. Gmail often ignores them entirely.

Comment: I would agree with @Blowski. When writing HTML for Email Campaigns I would suggest sticking with tables to offer consistency through out all email clients.